# Handling a browser dynamic value in Jmeter/Loadrunner

Tags: jsp, jmeter, loadrunner

I have an application where in the dynamic value is generating at the browser level. Since it is not in any of the responses, I cannot correlate in Jmeter/Loadrunner.
The workaround for now is to allow login without any validation and analyse the performance of remaining functionalities.
But is there a way we can go without skipping login?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible options:

1. The value is present somewhere in the response ([URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header) or body) and it can be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) (extracted from the previous response, saved into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and send with the next request)
2. The value is being generated in the browser via [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

   > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

   so if this is the case you need to replicate the logic of this JavaScript function using suitable JSR223 Test Element.

Comment: Yes Dmitri, 2nd scenario is where I am. Will look how to use JSR223 Test Element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JMeter [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) Plugin. Dynamic values will be handled by the WebDriver automatically.

Sample WebDriver Samplers demonstrating accessing the login page and submitting the credentials.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that Selenium code? I knew that we can use Jmeter+Selenium for Single Page Applications. But I started learning for this purpose now. Is this the only way??

Comment: 1. I have shared samples of Selenium WebDriver code. 2. There could be other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

"...dynamic value is generating at the browser level..."

You don't correlate this. It is not generated at the server, nor sent to the client.

Simply reproduce the code which produces the value in your script.  This is why testing tools have a general scripting language capability.   Use the JavaScript Code which produced this value.